# Downgrade php5 to 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2 in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-13.10

I recently updated to Ubuntu 13.10, and am having a versioning issue with PHP.

A client I have uses an older version of php5, of which the most current version that will work with it without deprecation errors is **5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2**. Ubuntu 13.10 ships with **5.5.3-1ubuntu2**.

I'd like to know if there is a way to get **5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2** to install on 13.10 without needing to resort to compiling source packages. I figure there must be a command line to apt-get to install an older version, which I'm just not aware of.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install php5=5.4.9-4ubuntu2.2` without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but why not simply remove E_DEPRECATED errors reporting for this client vhost instead of downgrading everything ?

Comment: Are you sure you've gotten those version numbers correct, because it read like you're trying to downgrade *from* 5.3.3 *to* 5.4.9, which doesn't exactly make sense.

Comment: You'd have to find a repository with that version. You can do `sudo apt-get update` to make sure you have a current listing of packages. If `sudo apt-get -s install php5` doesn't show the 5.4 version, google to see if another repository does.

Comment: @Sammitch Typo; correct version is 5.5.3.

Comment: @Lepidosteus Removing the deprecation errors isn't really a feasible course of action at this time. It would involve pulling an even more outdated version of PHP on the server to a more recent version, then totally rewriting the mysql classes, which the client would have to pay for.

Comment: @NathanCox Lepidosteus is saying to just disable the error reporting for E_DEPRECATED. The functions triggering those messages do not have any changed functionality from previous PHP versions, the messages are just there to notify developers that the functions will be removed in *future* versions of PHP. If it's the `mysql_*` functions you're worried about they're probably not going to disappear until 5.6 or later. eg: `error_reporting(error_reporting() ~E_DEPRECATED);` will turn off the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and found the following solution.  I'm testing it soon and will post back with results, but it looks solid.

```
# upgrade system, so you can add to ignore all updates later
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

# remove your php, apache, etc
sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 # add here your server packages

# change repositories to raring  (with backup)
sudo sed -i.bak "s/saucy/raring/g" /etc/apt/sources.list

# update and install server packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5 phpmyadmin 

# change repositories back to saucy
sudo sed -i "s/raring/saucy/g" /etc/apt/sources.list

# ignore all current upgrades (package hold)
dpkg --get-selections | egrep '^(apache|php)' | sed 's/install/hold/g' | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: I actually found a workaround in the PHP ini file that stopped the scripts from dieing on the deprecation errors, but this solution seems like a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`E_DEPRECATED` messages are *informational*, not to be considered on the same levels as even a warning. Their purpose is simply to inform developers that some functionality they are using will disappear in a future version.

From [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php):

> Run-time notices. Enable this to receive warnings about code that will not work in future versions.

While these notices may be useful in development, they should most certainly be disabled in production. You can do this by adding `~E_DEPRECATED` to your `error_reporting` line in php.ini, or by adding the following line to your script/application:

```
error_reporting(error_reporting() ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

[Function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

If I've read your comment correctly, these messages are stemming from your use of the `mysql_*` family of functions which were deprecated as of PHP 5.5. These functions are still *widely* in use and while they *could* be removed starting in PHP 5.6, it's still up for debate.

Short answer: you shouldn't have to downgrade anything, just turn down your error reporting settings a tad so they are not generated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main'    #add back raring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove php5-cli php5-common
sudo apt-get install php5-cli=5.4.9-4ubuntu2    #specify php version, lookup versions from: apt-cache policy php5-cli
sudo apt-mark hold php5-cli    #hold the version
```